# How do I run my python script on another computer?

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm, ide, python-3.7

How do I run my python script test.py, which I coded in Pycharm, to run on another computer, with no python and Pycharm installed?

The other system can have python installed but no Pycharm.

The script uses various excel files, does the other system need to create the same folder structure to read the file.

Comment: Pycharm is never necessary. It's just calling `python` and managing dependencies for you. You should be able to run your program directly on the command line using `python`.

Answer (score 3):

Convert that python file to a .exe file using `auto-py-to-exe`. This would convert your .py to .exe file which you can run anywhere.

To use auto-py-to-exe, just execute the following command on terminal `pip install auto-py-to-exe`.

Now on the terminal write `auto-py-to-exe` and press enter. Select the python file you wanna execute anywhere and click on `Convert .py to .exe` and you would get the folder containing .exe file. Transfer this folder to any computer and just by clicking the .exe file that is there inside the folder, the program would start executing normally no matter if the computer does not have python or pycharm installed.

Comment: Although, they said "The other system can have python installed". If that's an option, running it normally may be preferable.

Comment: @Sam Awesome!  so now they only need to create the same folder structure to read the excel files as per the code?

Comment: @Huma Just ensure that the excel files are included by you manually inside that folder which contains .exe file

Answer (score 0):

To run a python script from the command line of the other computer, try:

```
python -m test.py
```

If you need to run the script remotely, look into ssh.

You will need to recreate the file system on the other system and install any dependencies.

Comment: I used `python test.py` on my terminal. For the other system to run this, do I need to share just this test.py file or any other dependencies along? And also is there any specific location put this file, or any folder structure will do?

Comment: @Huma You don't need to do anything except simply making a .exe file as per the steps I mentioned. While your .py file gets converted to a .exe file, libraries used in that .py file automatically get converted to .exe.

Comment: @Huma You can put this folder anywhere on your laptop. Just remember that if you only want the .exe file only to show on the desktop (not the whole folder), then make a shortcut of .exe file on the desktop. Don't simply put the .exe file out of the folder anywhere you want. Also as mentioned, put the required excel files inside that folder, so that when .exe calls for that excel file, then it is present on the directory.

Comment: Video explanation of auto-py-to-exe by its creator https://youtu.be/OZSZHmWSOeM

Comment: Creating an executable handles all of the dependencies for you, but is platform specific. Using python in the terminal works on any platform. You need to install dependencies of test.py with pip if they aren't installed on the other system.